# using cursors and displaying row numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursors

I have declared the following cursor and have used a local variable `@RowNo` to print the number of each each row.

```
  declare TheCursor cursor 
  for select productName from products
  declare @RowNo int 
  declare @productName nvarchar(50)
  set @RowNo = 1
  open TheCursor
  fetch next from TheCursor into @productName
  print @RowNo
  print @productName
  set @RowNo = @RowNo+1
  set @productName=''

 while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
     fetch next from TheCursor into @productName
     print @RowNo
     print @productName
     set @RowNo = @RowNo+1
     set @productName=''
    end
 close TheCursor
 deallocate TheCursor
```

I am trying to find any other way to assign / define a number to each row and display it in the console. I have found the function `Row_number()` and used it like  `select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) As Rownumber` to do it.

I want to know if it is possible to use the `KEYSET` in my cursor to do it? How can I do it with `KEYSET`?

Comment: Keyset cursors save key columns to tempdb when the cursor is opened, and let you see concurrent changes made to non-key columns while you scroll through the cursor. Is this what you want? They have their place, but I doubt it's what you actually need. You ought to read the DECLARE CURSOR entry of BOL in more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: Also, KEYSET cursors may be incompatible w/ ROW_NUMBER(). Add TYPE_WARNING to your cursor declaration, and you will probably see a message that the cursor has been converted to STATIC.

Answer (score 2):

I don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve - but you could wrap your select statement including the `ROW_NUMBER()` function into a CTE (common table expression) and then go from there - no messy cursor needed, that really doesn't scale well:

```
WITH YourSelection AS
(
   SELECT    
      ProductName,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProductName) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM dbo.Products
)
SELECT ProductName, RowNum
FROM YourSelection
```

That should give you the product names, sorted by `ProductName`, and corresponding row numbers, too.

Comment: i have read that using keyset after the keyword cursor will assign a nuber to each of the rows and you can use these unique numbers. but i dont kn9ow how to use the keyset

Comment: I tried to steer Anna away from a cursor here as well: [solving a problem with cursors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608916/solving-a-problem-with-cursors/3609529#3609529). Not sure if it's the same Anna or not as they appear to be different user IDs, but the questions are quite similar.

Comment: @anna: if you ever can, simply try to **avoid** cursors all together. Try my approach - what do you need to do with this data once you have it??